# Avoid hard coding Heroku Procfile jar name?

Tags: java, heroku, procfile

My Spring Boot application has a project structure that is different from the default `target/<my-jar-file-name>.jar` path to a runnable jar.

My file is located at `backend/target/<my-jar-file-name>.jar`.

The solution is to create a Heroku `Procfile`:

`web: java -jar backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

But given this, every time I update my program version, this file would also have to be updated.

Are there any automated ways of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

First, you can use a wildcard in the `Procfile`:

```
web: java -jar backend/target/backend-*.jar
```

But depending on how you build works, that could match more than one file.

Second option is to name your executable without the version in your `pom.xml`. You can do this with the `finalName` element like:

```
<build>
    <finalName>backend</finalName>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. I like the first solution.